# Activator Createinstance object to class of T

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to cast object to class of T and return it.

Entity framework class:

```
public partial class Unicorn 
{
     public string ColorCode { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }


    public Unicorn() { }

}
```

Convert function:

```
 private T ConvertMagicObjectTo<T>(object obj) where T : new()
 {
     return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), obj);
 }
```

And when I run:

```
var strongUnicorn = ConvertMagicObjectTo<Unicorn>(myTestObj);
```

I'm getting error "constructor not found", eventhough Unicorn.cs class has a constructor.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your selected overload of CreateInstance expects a constructor with 1 parameter. Remove the `obj` argument.

Comment: Please give example of using this code. Because right now this code makes no sense and i think we should rewrite it completely

Comment: Side note: why do you require `T:new()` but use `CreateInstance` to create object?

Comment: If you're trying to _cast_ object to `T`, just cast it, you don't need to create a new instance: `var strongUnicorn = (Unicorn)myTestObj;`. It seems to me that there's more to your code that you show here.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly what additional code you are looking for? As it stands now post provides all pieces that demonstrate problem (including exact exception message - which indeed is very confusing)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i would never write this code myself because it has some bad practices and violates type safety. By knowing the purpose of that code we could suggest a better way.

Comment: The purpose is to convert a list of magical strings from an application and convert them, and insert them into a new database using entity framework.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly I don't get your point - the question to me looks like "I'm getting the error that makes no sense. Here is MVCE". I don't see anywhere in the question that OP looking for better way of doing something or any signs of code shown being release quality code... Even if you don't make any mistakes ever does not mean other people are as lucky :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the convert method is failing because you are trying to call the [CreateInstance method with a constructor argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx) and the type Unicorn has no constructor that accepts arguments.

Instead, since you added the `new()` generic constraint, you may want to create a new local object using the empty constructor and populate it like this:

```
private T ConvertMagicObjectTo<T>(object src) where T : new()
{
    var dest = new T();
    // map source to dest
    return dest;
}
```

or alternatively create a constructor that accepts an argument:

```
public Unicorn(object src)
{
   // map source to local instance.
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution I was looking for. I'll google the mapping part :) thx

Answer (score 6):

You are passing one object to [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx), which means that a constructor with one parameter is necessary.  The `Unicorn` constructor has no parameters.  Either add a parameter to the constructor or remove it from the call to `CreateInstance`.

It's unclear what the purpose of `myTestObj` is in order to know if it should be used as part of the construction, or what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ConvertMagicObjectTo<T>` doesn't convert `obj` to T, it creates a new instance of T and passes `obj` to the constructor. The Unicorn class doesn't have a constructor that accepts 1 parameter, that's why you get the error.

You don't need any special method to cast an object to another type.
Just use

```
var strongUnicorn = (Unicorn)myTestObj;
```

if you know that `myTestObj` can be cast to Unicorn or

```
var strongUnicorn = myTestObj as Unicorn;
if (strongUnicorn != null)
{
    //do something with it
}
```